# How do I get to the two puzzle pieces right at the end of Cloud Bridge?

Tags: braid

At the end of the Cloud Bridge section of the first level there are two puzzle pieces. How do I reach them?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a while -- have you tried jumping on the platform *inside* the picture? (The one that is itself on the puzzle piece) It might look like just another jigsaw piece, but it'll support your weight just fine.

Move it around until you're able to jump from the platform to the left of the puzzle to the right side of the puzzle. This'll let you reach the top jigsaw.

I remember less about the puzzle piece directly above the exit door. Looks like you need a Goomba, which you may need to "escort" to the end of the map via moving the puzzle-jigsaw platform, as for the above piece.

Comment: Do I need to use the Goomba to get to the other piece above the door?

Comment: @SolCrenshaw Yes, place the platform puzzle piece next to the left side so that the Goomba who's walking back and forth walks onto it. Once they do, move the puzzle piece and the platform out from under it. The Goomba will fall to the ground, and you can then use him to reach the puzzle piece.